# Problem with Axios and extra slash when used with Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, vue.js, axios

Time for me to ask some help as I simply do not understand the issue, spent a good 6 hours on this, going nowhere :-(

I have an Axios GET request which may have the last parameter empty.

```
axios.get(this.fetchAllUsersRoute + '/' + this.status + '/' + this.pagination + '/' + this.search);
```

My laravel route:

```
Route::get('/fetch-users/{status}/{pagination}/{search?}', 'MyController@fetchUsers')->name('fetch-users');
```

When the this.search is empty I am getting this:

```
Request URL: https://mywebsite.dev/fetch-users/0/1/
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 301 Moved Permanently (from disk cache)
```

It redirects to here on each request:

```
https://mywebsite.dev/fetch-users/0/1
```

The last / slash seems to be causing a redirection when this value is left empty.

As soon as I remove it, the problem stops...no redirection.

Any idea how I can make the last slash disappear if the last value is empty?

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide the link you are requesting as an example.

Answer (score 2):

Your request is incompatible with the route. You can try to create request link like below.

```
var fetchAllUsersRoute = "https://mywebsite.dev"
var status = 'status'
var pagination = 'pagination'
var search

var url = fetchAllUsersRoute + '/' + status + '/' + pagination + (search != null ? ('/' + search) : '')

console.log(url)
// "https://mywebsite.dev/status/pagination"

search = 'search'

url = fetchAllUsersRoute + '/' + status + '/' + pagination + (search != null ? ('/' + search) : '')

console.log(url)
// "https://mywebsite.dev/status/pagination/search"
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. So this is how most people would do it when one of the GET parameters is(from time to time) empty? Using ternary operators? Is this common?